# Javascript for loop to add multiple items

Tags: javascript, arrays

My end goal is an array something like the one below:

```
let nodes_data =  [
    {"id": "A", "depth": 1, "x":50, "y":100},
    {"id": "B", "depth": 2, "x":150, "y":200},
    {"id": "C", "depth": 2, "x":250, "y":200},
    {"id": "D", "depth": 3, "x":350, "y":300},
]
```

However, I am only starting with an id and depth, and I would like to calculate the x and y separately.

So, given the starting source array of:

```
let nodes_data =  [
    {"id": "A", "depth": 1},
    {"id": "B", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "C", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "D", "depth": 3},
]
```

I tried to do a for loop to add to the array:

```
 function presetCoordinates(data){
 let nodes = [];
  for ( let i = 0; i< nodes_data.length; i++) {
    y = data[i].depth*100;
    x = (i*100) + 50;

    nodes.push(x, y)
  }
  return nodes;
}

let nodes_with_coords = presetCoordinates(nodes_data)
console.log(nodes_with_coords)
```

Where `nodes_with_coords` is my "goal" array.

but I'm getting some really strange results. Any thoughts on what I'm missing here? I think maybe I'm over-complicating this.

Comment: Use professional language please...

Comment: What is the current result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "[Array.map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)" for this like below.

What map does is, it loops over every element in "nodes_data" and returns new object/array/{whatever} you need, in your case new object with more data.

```js
let nodes_data =  [
    {"id": "A", "depth": 1},
    {"id": "B", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "C", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "D", "depth": 3},
]

let res = nodes_data.map((d, i) => ({...d, x: i * 100 + 50, y: d.depth * 100 }))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't include the original object:

```js
function presetCoordinates(data) {
  let nodes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nodes_data.length; i++) {
    y = data[i].depth * 100;
    x = (i * 100) + 50;
    
    // include the contents of the original node using spread
    nodes.push({ ...data[i], x, y }) 
  }
  return nodes;
}

let nodes_data =  [
    {"id": "A", "depth": 1},
    {"id": "B", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "C", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "D", "depth": 3},
]

let nodes_with_coords = presetCoordinates(nodes_data)
console.log(nodes_with_coords)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the required result.

**Demo**

```js
const nodes_data =  [
    {"id": "A", "depth": 1},
    {"id": "B", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "C", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "D", "depth": 3},
];

let i = 0;

let result = nodes_data.reduce((r, o) => {
  let x = i + 50,
    y = i + 100;
  i = y;
  return [...r, Object.assign({},o,{x,y})];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Array.map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
 it simply straight forward

```
function presetCoordinates(arr){
    return arr.map(function(data, idx){

        data.x = (idx * 100) + 50; 
        data.y = data.depth * 100; 
        return data;        
    });
}

var nodes_data =  [
    {"id": "A", "depth": 1},
    {"id": "B", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "C", "depth": 2},
    {"id": "D", "depth": 3},
];

let nodes_with_coords = presetCoordinates(nodes_data)
console.log(nodes_with_coords)
```